# Open online searchable book review database

Tags: data-request, historical, text

In my quest for [a story identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5533/542) I'm looking for a publicly available searchable database of book reviews such as published in newspapers and magazines.  I've found several such databases, such as through [gale](https://www.gale.com/uk/c/book-review-index-plus), [Boston College](https://proxy.bc.edu/login?url=https://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?authtype=ip,uid&profile=ehost&defaultdb=brd,brr), and the [New York Public Library](https://www.nypl.org/collections/articles-databases/book-review-index-online), but it appears all require membership.  Is there any such database publicly available?

I'm interested in answers covering either English, Dutch, or multilingual solutions.  I can search [Dutch newspapers online](https://www.delpher.nl/nl/kranten/) (until 1995).  This will (presumably) cover book reviews published in those newspapers, but (as far as I know) does not offer an easy way to search for only the reviews.